# Best way forward for married veteran and caregiver couple to immigrate to Canada from US

Tags: immigration, canada, us-citizens

Is there a path to permanent residency for a married couple (a disabled veteran, and his full-time caregiver wife) to move to Canada from the US? I've been over the [Immigration and Citizenship](https://www.canada.ca/en/services/immigration-citizenship.html) pages but nothing quite seems to fit. The rub seems to be that neither person would be moving to Canada to work. The vet has guaranteed disability income from Veterans Affairs no matter where on Earth he resides.

They would ultimately like to buy a house here and apply for citizenship in five years when they're eligible, and continue to live on the disability benefit from the VA. Is this even possible under the current immigration rules? If so, under what program should they apply?

Failing that, are there any other options?

Comment: Have you reviewed [Canada's Immigration overview web page](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada.html)? That and the Wikipedia page on [Canada's Visa Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Canada) are good introductions. If you don't see a viable route, you should consult with a Canadian attorney versed in Canadian immigration issues.

Comment: Canada does rule [some immigrants medically inadmissable](https://www.temporaryresidentpermitcanada.com/medical-inadmissibility.php). In your case, it would be if your medical care is over about CAD$7k/year. Note: link goes to a non-governmental immigration site. Note2: looks like the amount at least has changed recently to around CAD$21k/yr